# Python tkinter PhotoImage not working well?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

**Why do my Tkinter images not appear?**

i wrote this code

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()


def ouvrir():
    global image
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="\Khaoula\Desktop\open_cv_book", title="Select a file",filetypes=(("jpg files", "*.jpg"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(root.filename))


button = Button(root, text="Open File", command=ouvrir)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**No errors

But the picture didn't show up**

Could you help please ?

Comment: You just create an instance of `ImageTk.PhotoImage` but do not use it in any `Label` or `Canvas`.

Comment: Yes You are right ! Thak you sooo much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the code you have given above :
You are just creating an instance of that image.
If you want the window to show up the image then you should call it up on Labels/Button/Canvas.

Hope it will help!

Comment: Yes Right 
Thaaank youu